# How can I get a single php file that is the equivalent of an existing WordPress page?

Tags: php, templates

When I use my php file as a template and no other content on the page, it works fine but when I run the file directly (via PhpStorm), there are missing elements (such as comment_status) that cause exceptions.  I am doing the require of wp-load and calling get_header() within the file, but obviously something is still missing, that a 'real' WP page has.  So - I'd like to see the Php from the otherwise 'blank' page, that WP uses.  Viewing source of course only shows the final html.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: BlankPage */
require_once '..\wp-load.php';
get_header();

comments_template();
comment_form();
get_footer();
?>
```

When used as a template, the 'require' line is commented out.
Via the WP page editor, I checked the 'allow comments' checkbox.  Don't know how to do that yet, via the code.

Comment: can you please update your question with the exact code.

Comment: Yes, did that.  But an answer to my current problem would not address the question I asked.  And - I think I know the answer to the comment status issue; it is probably not possible to comment on a php file; only a WP page, and the comment status of that page would be held in the DB, not applicable to some external file that you might load.

Comment: Have a look at this, this might help you,
[link](https://www.damiencarbery.com/2017/01/standalone-wordpress-scripts-what-do-they-do-how-to-secure-them/)

Comment: You can use `comments_open()` for allow comments in the code it's similar that checked allow comments checkbox

Comment: comments_open() is a 'getter', not a 'setter'.  Adding it to the code just throws the same exception that it cannot retrieve the comment_status.  If you mean that I should override the function, would need a bit more guidance on how to do that for a specific php file, without opening up comments for every page on the site.